# JSON schema: Use field value as required field name

Tags: jsonschema

I need to define a JSON schema for a JSON in which a field/key is called as the value of a previous field. Examples:

```
{
  "key1": "SOME_VALUE",
  "SOME_VALUE": "..."
}
```

```
{
  "key1": "ANOTHER_VALUE",
  "ANOTHER_VALUE": "..."
}
```

Moreover, the second field should be among the required ones.
I have been looking around but I am not sure JSON schema offers such feature. Maybe some advanced semantics check?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to [Relequestual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89211/relequestual) suggestions, I managed to get to a solution.

**Constraint: possible values of "key1" need to be finite and known in advance**

Suppose we need a JSON schema for validating a JSON that:

1. Requires the string properties "required_simple_property1" and "required_simple_property2".
2. Requires the property "key1" as an enum with 3 possible values ["value1", "value2", "value3"].
3. Requires a third property, whose key must be the value taken by key1.

This can be accomplished with a schema like:

```
"oneOf": [
    {
        "required": [
            "required_simple_property1",
            "required_simple_property2",
            "value1"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string",
                "const": "value1"
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "required": [
            "required_simple_property1",
            "required_simple_property2",
            "value2"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string",
                "const": "value2"
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "required": [
            "required_simple_property1",
            "required_simple_property2",
            "value3"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "string",
                "const": "value3"
            }
        } 
    }
],
"properties": {
    "required_simple_property1": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "required_simple_property2": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "value1": {
        ... (anything)
    },
    "value2": {
        ... (anything)
    },
    "value3": {
        ... (anything)
    },
}
```

Comment: Actually, "required" : ["required_simple_property1", "required_simple_property2"] could be taken off the "oneOf"

Comment: Moreover, to avoid having properties "value2" and "value3" when "key1": "value1", it should be needed to either have "additionalProperties": false, or (if other random properties want to be allowed) to add on any of the "oneOf" cases a "not": {"required": ["value2", "value3"]} ...

Comment: Actually for requiring that none of multiple fields are presents, the pattern is putting under "not" an "anyOf" with all of the required combinations to avoid (in the comment above only if both "value2" and "value3" are present the JSON will be rejected)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this is if you knew the values in advance, but it looks like this is not possible for you. This would need to be in your business logic validation as opposed to your format validation.

Comment: So, maybe if I restricted "key1" values to an enum, I might add requirements to only one of the values of the enum (which I know in advance). However, I would still not know how to check that the second field key (one of the requirements) is equal to the value of "key1".

Comment: Yeah. Do you know what draft of JSON Schema you are able to use?

Comment: JSON Schema Draft 7

Comment: Super. So you can use `const` which is the same as a singular enum, and you can use `propertyNames` (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.8) to validate a property name. I'll update my question to reflect, but maybe that will be enough to get you started. BTW, you can test your schemas using https://jsonschema.dev